# Use Reflection to Recurse Through an Object and Print Tree

Tags: c#, .net, oop, reflection, recursion

If I have a predefined object in C#, how can I loop through the object's structure using reflection to print so it looks like the following:

```
Class PurchaseOrder
------------------
Property: ID     | Type: Int32
Property: Client | Type: Some.Namespace.Client
+----   Property: FirstName | Type: String
+----   Property: LastName  | Type: String
+----   Property: Address   | Type: Some.Namespace.Address
+----   +----    Property: Line1 | Type: String
Property: Date   | Type: DateTime
```

I want to recurse through the structure of the object (not caring about the actual data inside, but only the name of the property and a type). Additionally, if it's not a base type, keep recursing down the tree (i.e. an object or a list).

NOTE: Only public members...

I can't seem to picture this for some reason.

Here's what the C# classes would look like for the above printed tree:

```
class PurchaseOrder {
    public Int32 Id {get;set;}
    public Client Client {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}

class Client {
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName  {get;set;}
    public Address Address {get;set}
}

class Address {
    public string Line1 {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

However, ideally this would work for any type.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: So what part are you stuck on?  What about fields or methods?

Comment: @JeffreyKevinPry You don't necessarily need recursion for this problem. You can also solve it iteratively.  If you do that first, then you should be at least one step closer to seeing the parts of the algorithm that could potentially become recursive.

Comment: Wouldn't recursion be the most elegant way to complete this?

Comment: @JeffreyKevinPry Maybe, but should that really be the focus *at first*? Get it to work first, and improve it iteratively.

Comment: @JeffreyKevinPry George is right. What you'll want to do is create a function that returns a property and the type. Then you check to see if the type is `object`. If it isn't, you call the function again to keep drilling down. Actually a `while` loop seems more efficient for this then recursion.

Comment: Not sure what the downvote is for? Care to explain? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be very easy to do it using [ObjectDumper](http://objectdumper.codeplex.com/).

It's an opensource tool written by Microsoft that seem to do exactly what you want : write a textual/readable representation of an object properties. It's a simple class that is very easy to modify if you want to adapt the outpout format.

Simplest usage example:

```
ObjectDumper.Write(purchaseOrder)
```

Check [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/08/14/object-dumper-an-invaluable-tool-for-writing-code-in-the-functional-programming-style.aspx) for usage samples.

Comment: Actually I think this is exactly what I am looking for!